# Where is the default constraint name preserved?

Tags: postgresql, default-constraint

In the context of SQL Server the default constraints are objects that can be queried via system views. I am migrating a table from T-SQL to Postgres and end up with the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE public.EntitiesSQLObjectNamesMapping
(
    RecordGuid UUID  NOT NULL,
    IsInterfaceView BIT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_EntitiesSQLObjectNamesMapping_IsInterfaceView DEFAULT (0::bit)
);
```

As you can see I am allowed to set a name to the default constraint, but I can't find the system view which is holding this name:

```
SELECT *
FROM pg_catalog.pg_constraint;

select *
from information_schema.columns col
where col.column_default is not null
      and col.table_schema not in('information_schema', 'pg_catalog')
order by col.column_name;
```

Also, in the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/ddl-default.html) I even can see no information about this and the syntax itself.

Can anyone point me where this info is available?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "default constraint". It's a default **value**. I am surprised Postgres even accepts that syntax. But as far as I can tell it's simply ignored because NOT NULL constraints never get a name. (Btw: flags are better defined as `boolean`, a `bit`  is something different)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I already read this in one of your answers :D but I want to keep the things the same as possible. It's strange that the syntax is working ...